# accessing certain fields of row data in skip_row()

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-import-export

I want to skip rows if data is duplicate while importing excel. The duplication logic is applicable to only certain cells but not entire row.

How do I access certain fields of row data for applying criteria in skip_row()

Edit: When I did this

`def skip_row(self, instance, original):
        print('instance:', instance)
        print('original:', original)`

`original` is always being `None` and `instance` is printing random fields from row data.

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to achieve this using `getattr(instance, 'column_value')`

Suppose we are importing an excel with columns id, name and age. 
We can write as:

```
def skip_row(self, instance, original):
   ..................................
   print(getattr(instance, 'id'))
   print(getattr(instance, 'name')) 
   print(getattr(instance, 'age'))
   ..................................
```